# I want to remove cookies by its domain on firefox extension

Tags: cookies, firefox-addon

I develop Firefox extension, but I can't remove cookie with specified domain.  I want to remove cookie with **specified domain** on Firefox extension
example:
remove cookies of domain https://www.facebook.com

Comment: So what do you have now? I'm hoping your extension can do more because you know you can remove cookies in FireFox via settings right?

Comment: i want remove cookie with specified domain on Firefox extension by Code

Comment: You need to do a little research.  I just googled for half a minute "cookies firefox code" and stumbled onto how you interface with them though firefox' API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Cookies Come back when you have some base line code and we can help you more.

Comment: thank you but i want to remove cookies with specified domain not all cookies Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;.getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager).removeAll();

Comment: Then what about this funciton? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Removing_a_cookie It even allows for a domain to be specified.

Comment: thanks a lot this is ok, but i don't know name of cookie i only know its domain.

Answer (score 0):

And I want cookies... Wait what?!

More seriously, you likely got your downvotes by saying "I want..." and not demonstrating that you made any attempt or at least did any research to solve this on your own.

Anyway:

1. Use [`nsICookieManager2.getCookiesFromHost`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager2#getCookiesFromHost%28%29) and/or [`nsICookieManager.enumerator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager#Attributes) to get a list of cookies. See also: [Reading existing cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Cookies#Reading_existing_cookies)
2. Filter the cookies by your criteria, making sure your code doesn't remove more cookies than it needs to.
3. Remove the cookies you collected with [`nsICookieManager.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager#remove%28%29).
4. Bonus: Use the [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieService#Notifications) to listen for any new cookies and get rid of them.